# custom module of magento not working on live

Tags: magento

I have created a custom module from:
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/14163/adding-custom-attribute-to-customer.
And this is successfully working on local but not working on live:
my config.xml (app/code/local/Your/Customattribute/etc/config.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Your_Customattribute>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Your_Customattribute>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <resources>
            <Your_Customattribute_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Your_Customattribute</module>
                    <class>Mage_Customer_Model_Entity_Setup</class>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </Your_Customattribute_setup>
            <Your_Customattribute_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </Your_Customattribute_write>
            <Your_Customattribute_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </Your_Customattribute_read>
        </resources>
    </global>
</config>
```

And my next file is install-0.1.0.php(app/code/local/Your/Customattribute/sql/your_customattribute_setup/install-0.1.0.php):

```
<?php
$installer = $this;

$installer->startSetup();

$setup = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');

$entityTypeId     = $setup->getEntityTypeId('customer');
$attributeSetId   = $setup->getDefaultAttributeSetId($entityTypeId);
$attributeGroupId = $setup->getDefaultAttributeGroupId($entityTypeId, $attributeSetId);

$installer->addAttribute("customer", "customattribute",  array(
"type"     => "varchar",
"backend"  => "",
"label"    => "Custom Attribute",
"input"    => "text",
"source"   => "",
"visible"  => true,
"required" => false,
"default" => "",
"frontend" => "",
"unique"     => false,
"note"       => "Custom Attribute"

    ));

    $attribute   = Mage::getSingleton("eav/config")->getAttribute("customer", "customattribute");


$setup->addAttributeToGroup(
$entityTypeId,
$attributeSetId,
$attributeGroupId,
'customattribute',
'999'  //sort_order
);
```

Please tell me where I am going wrong.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: if your local server is on Windows then any of the difference in file naming could cause this if your hosting is linux hosting...

Comment: yes my system is of windows and my live server is on linx. But I am not able to see any error. please help if you are able to.

Comment: have you cleared the cache on live, after installation of module ?

Comment: yes, cache and session cleared.

Comment: Now I am getting Error in file: "app/code/local/Your/Customattribute/sql/your_customattribute_setup/install-0.1.0.php" - SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'your_customattribute_setup' for key 'PRIMARY'

Comment: it worked after changing "Your_Customattribute_setup" to "your_customattribute_setup"

Answer (score 0):

If your local server is on Windows then any of the difference in file naming or case could cause this if your hosting is linux hosting..

Also, clear the cache on live, after installation of module